# Javaagent throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/PreparedStatement with java 15

Tags: java, javaagents

Java agent is throwing this error when running with a java 15 app, if anybody can shed a light on why this might be coming, it will be very helpful.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/PreparedStatement
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3325)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2466)
.
.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.PreparedStatement
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how it helps others to reproduce your problem and answer your question. Then edit your question, improving it accordingly. Specifically, show your code. Nobody can debug a stacktrace out of context. Please also explain why you think this problem is specific to Java 15. Did the same code run on previous Java versions? If so, which ones?

Comment: Does your `URLClassLoader` delegate to the Platform ClassLoader?

Answer (score 0):

Class not found Exception happens when JVM Doesn't find the class files on the classpath. Either the auto deployment feature(auto-deployment="true") is erroneous or you don't have class file(sql jar) on the classpath. If you are using Maven, Just check if sql jar(prepared statement class file and sql jar file) is on the classpath. If class file not on classpath, Just add the class file manually on classpath. It should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

It means java.sql.PreparedStatement is available at compile time but not available at Runtime.
To solve the issue add the sql jar to classpath, if you are using maven add dependency in pom.xml.